# Android Studio Logcat Filter does not show up

Tags: filter, android-studio, logcat, device

I'm using AndroidStudio 0.4.0 (encountered same problem on 0.3.2) on Ubuntu 13.10. 
Everything was ok till I lose the logcat Filtering utility and device choosing side bar in 'Android' and 'ddms ddms' views.

However the program recognize connected device/emulator and runs the app normally on it, it even shows all logs roughly, but **I no longer can select device or filter the logs**.

How can I recover them?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can add the whole studio screenshot with DDMS opened , need to confirm something.

Comment: Not sure correctly understood your comment but I can still open these views using View > Tool Windows > Android and there's no ask confirmation...

Comment: i asked for screen shot of android studio's whole screen ddms opened in that  not only the ddms part.

Comment: No, actually it's all what's showing up each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be rather based on Ubuntu packages auto-update. After searching all over internet this page helped out to recover the views.

http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2013/10/23/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-linux-13-10/

I installed these two packages and relaunched the Studio, everything works fine again.

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to make it appear. Just click the "Event log" label in the bottom-right of AS.

But it may will miss again in some case... I guess whether it's a bug of AS.

Same question, check this link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714646/logcat-is-missing-the-filters-options/52959720#52959720)