# Android studio: not showing filter option

Tags: android-studio

[image]

My android-studio logcat not showing filter option. I think some settings has been changed.

Comment: please be more specific, update your OS and studio version. If possible include a screenshot as well.

Comment: @pyus13 specific means wht? i have shared screenshot n os is Ubantu linux

Comment: sorry proxy server blocked the image so could not see. check this of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006416/android-studio-logcat-filter-does-not-show-up/21051429#21051429

Comment: was it working earlier or you are facing the problem from beginning ?

Comment: yes,It was working earlier.I think there should be something in settings, r u using Android Studio?

Comment: obviously man but on Windows! I don't think there is some setting to make filter invisible. Are you able to see filter in devices tab ? And what you did after that you think it got invisible. I think there is something missing in setup.

Comment: Yes,I can see filter in devices tab.By mistake it is closed by me.

Comment: You can make it visible again by clicking on a icon which appeared on top right corner after the place where usually we see our filter option.

Comment: I think u r not getting my question,can u please check that screenshot posted in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem as you, including after complete clean (format disk) install of Ubuntu 13.04 and clean install of everything.

Today I finally figured out some magic window/tab drag operation. I'm on Android Studio 0.42 as of this posting.

I don't really know how to describe the drag operation, and I'm a bit afraid to undo it for screenshots ;)

Tabs:

[ Devices ]  [ Logcat ] [ ADB Logs ]

While on devices (while filters and everything on the right are there), drag the logcat window INTO the frame, somewhat below the tab bar.

They then stack so you can see the Filter AND the logcat on the same window.  Then it will look like this:

[ Devices | Logcat ] [ ADB Logs ]

only two tabs (note the vertical bar), with the first tab holding merged content.

Comment: Also found you can drag the ADB Logs into the same frame, so they all 3 are | on same tab