# How to find filter Logcat configuration in Android Studio 1.0?

Tags: android, windows, android-logcat, android-filter, android-log

I know how to do the actual logcat filtering but I can't find the icon for it. This is a view of the Logcat demonstration that I am following. 
[image]

I saw that this is the standard view for Logcat - [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio). 
However this is what mine looks like. 
[image]

Is there any way I can get the rest of the stuff to show up - Log level, filter, etc?
I am running Windows 8 64 bit operating system. These didn't help because in both cases, the user was running a Ubuntu operating system - [Android Studio Logcat Filter does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006416/android-studio-logcat-filter-does-not-show-up?lq=1).  and [Android studio: not showing filter option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131339/android-studio-not-showing-filter-option?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Android Studio are you using, I am running on Windows 7 + AS 1.0.2 and the wordings and layout is different than yours.

In any case, in my "**ADB Logs**" view, I see the same thing as you:
[image]

But when I switch to "**Devices | logcat**" view, the filter is shown and can be used correctly:
[image]

So my suggestion would be to update Android Studio and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this filter text box what you are looking for?

[image: Android Studio Log Filter Location]