# LogCat is missing the filters options

Tags: android-studio

[image]

The filters are on the devices tab. But isn't this supposed to be in logcat?

How do you reset them back?

Comment: This seems related to plugging in my actual nexus 5x instead of using a virtual machine.  Must not support remote logging maybe?  I actually can see the filters and then they went away when I plugged in a real device.

Comment: now I see the filter with my actual android so I guess its a random bug.

Comment: Also, the Debug pane does not appear to support filtering. Only the LogCat pane does. I'm hoping this comment helps people with my point of confusion.

Comment: Years later and I, myself, am having this issue. Not a single answer from below fixed it. The bug might just be bigger, now.

Comment: Still an issue 8 years later, which is a bit farcical.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Exit and restart Android Studio and it should be fixed.

Interestingly, the first time I tried to re-open Android Studio I got a crash.  But the second time it worked fine.  Perhaps there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: restart did not bring back any filter option and I have tried right-clicking everywhere in and around the log with no joy.  did they remove this option?

Comment: Same here on macOS Android Studio 3.1 AI-173.4670197 from 22 march 2018. Simple restart AS do not help - Filter bar completely disappeared

Comment: I restarted AS when the Logcat wasn't updating properly and when I reopened it, the Logcat filters were missing. I restarted again and they reappeared. 
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I restarted before I read this answer once. It didnt help. Restarting again after reading this did. Looks like it needs multiple restarts sometimes.

Comment: "Perhaps a bug somewhere" ??  Two years later, this is still an issue.  Stop/Start fixed it, but this environment is a bug infested... Still!   Menus, windows, tools, all vanish and you spend more time trying to get the environment settings back than actual coding.

Comment: This problem is still there in Android Studio 3.3. Restarting once fixed it for me.

Comment: @ManishChandraJoshi R.Mohanraj's answer below is much more solid if that helps

Comment: Restarting the AS will not work rather click on the EVENT LOG and see the filters are back.

Comment: I had the same problem and I closed the Android Studio and opened again all the stuff on the Logcat panel came back.

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidade and Restart

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed thank you, Internet stranger. Really worked :)

Answer (score 452):

There is a way to make it appear. 
Just click the "**Event log**" label in the bottom-right of AS.

But it may will miss again in some case... I guess whether it's a bug of AS.

> This bug is still existing in Android Studio 3.5 the lastest stable version, I got it just now(08/26/2019 3:13PM).

Comment: Event log did it. But why?

Comment: I don't know... It's may a bug of Android studio.

Comment: This fixed the issue. I can't believe that the bug can be reproduced in the latest version of android studio.

Comment: I dealt with that issue today. I too was losing my mind. It's weird that we were forced to explicitly press the Event Log icon.

Comment: I guess sometimes when logcat opens it doen't draw filters due a bug. Clicking Event log forces the entire panel to redraw and then make filter show up.

Comment: The bug still persists in Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, running on Ubuntu. Clicking Event log did the trick for me.

Comment: @Licat Julius "do the trick" means "to achieve the desired result". Your solution helped me and I upvoted it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I was tired of closing and opening Android Studio again every morning.

Comment: @taxo thank you. because the translator tells me 'trick' == 'cheat' in Chinese... so I was confused, lol... I got it now, thank you.

Comment: @LicatJulius Thank you! Restart and toggling floating mode didn't help, but opening/closing Event log did the trick.

Comment: @sesm That's my pleasure.

Comment: This bug still exists in Android Studio 3.4.2 Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @MarkSitro Yeah, I had it yesterday. same 3.4.2 version.

Comment: This happened today on Android Studio 3.5. Restarting AS didn't fix it. Your suggestion however did fix it! Thank you so much.

Comment: This is being tracked by google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140508076. I hope they fix it before Elon Musk sends people to Mars.

Comment: @function1983 Because this will recreate the Logcat.

Comment: My logcat is pinned to the left side instead of default bottom. This 'fix' only worked when I first moved my logcat back to the bottom.

Comment: happed with me in Android Studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 147):

Had this problem on Android Studio 3.2 Beta 4 (Windows 64-bit). Toggling 'Floating Mode' on and off again made the filters reappear. Bit faster than exiting Android Studio if you're lucky enough.

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 is a disaster.

Comment: This worked for me! You can find the option on the main menu "Window"/"Active Tool Window"/"Floating Mode". Turn it on and off!

Comment: @TatiOverflow agree with you. Try 3.2.1 it has lots of bug fixes.

Comment: Worked for me too. THat's fast! I will try that as the first option next time it happens.

Comment: @Ancee, I'm getting the bug in Android Studio 3.2.1, so it might not be fixed yet.

Comment: @Sam. Yup, agreed with you. I got the same bug yesterday. I have to restart android studio and that always waste lots time.

Comment: with right click on `Logcat` you can also toggle the `Floating Mode`. Worked for me aswell

Comment: I'm still getting this bug in 3.4.  Toggling fixed.

Comment: This also fixed for Android 3.5 preview

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need to restart Android Studio.

Comment: agreed, toggling floating mode worked for me - should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 128):

[image][See This Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTScZ.png), Bottom of android studio left side corner click the rectangle icon.

Comment: The perfect answer

Comment: Finally, there is an answer

Comment: Thank you. Before your answer, I was in troubling.

Comment: Thanks Bro, It Worked

Comment: This is the alternative when the Event Log stops appearing side by side with Logcat.

Comment: thanks, this the right answer, i was trying sequentially everything posted in every answer and comment but nothing worked...finally this worked with a single click

Comment: Thats the perfect solution

Answer (score 42):

Restart Android Studio didn't help me, nor toggling floating mode, but clicking the "Event log" label in the bottom-right of AS did the trick!

Comment: Seems like bug in Android Studio.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by setting viewmode for logcat to a separate window and the switching view mode back to "Dock Pinned".  Right click on the top bar of and you will see view mode option.  It will essentially reset logcat.

[image: 1) switch from dock pinned to window]

[image: 2) switch back from window to dock pinned]

Comment: Thanks! Works everytime, and is by far the easiest option

Answer (score 13):

I fixed by changing its location. Click Setting -> Move to -> Left Top : The logcat reappeared. After that, change it to the previous location. Click Setting -> Move to -> Bottom Left

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.

**File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart** solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Bug still occurs in Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312. What worked for me is clicking the Event Log then it shows.

Answer (score 8):

I faced  the same problem in Android Studio 3.3 and by Toggling 'Floating Mode' on and off, the filters appeared.Hope it will help in your case also.

Answer (score 7):

Just right click on the title bar of it and switch to windowed mode then go back to your mode...

Answer (score 7):

Still having the problem with AS 3.5 which is awful! Fixing it every time by switching logcat window **view mode** from **dock pinned** to **float** and changing it back to **dock pinned again**.

Opened an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141319502) for the team to fix it. Consider starring it to get more attention, or sharing your own experience to help find the culprit.

Comment: great temp solution

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshort of LogCat of Android Studio]

I resolved this issue by selecting 'split mode' from the setting option of the top right corner of LogCat section of Android Studio

Happy Android Coding!
Hope this will save anyone's time!

Answer (score 2):

Simple

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidade and Restart

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It didn't ever happened before on my PC, but now I'm using Mac and many bad things happens.

I tried to fix it by the above solutions, but nothing worked for me. What eventually did work was double clicking the toolbar (to maximize tool window).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to Setting Right Top, just Click Show Tool

Answer (score 0):

I synced the files and then restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I tired closing and reopening Android Studio and even restarting my mac and nothing worked. Instead of closing Android Studio I did invalidate cache and restart under the tab file in Android Studio and everything seems to be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I fixed in Mac by double clicking toolbar window to maximize as comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried restarting a couple of times but that did not bring the filter menu in Logcat tab. However, in my case, it was also showing a pop-up notification to update the IDE. I updated it and got the filter option back.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

On your android studio press **ALT+6**

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio settings, go to Experimental and unvalidate the "Enable new logcat" and restart your android studio, it will work.