# Logcat Filter missing in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio, logcat

After updating from Android Studio 3.2 to 3.3 the LogCat filtering options are no longer present, and a quick search through the Android Studio settings doesn't reveal any option to bring them back.

How do you show/hide the logcat filter options in Android Studio 3.3?

Comment: Are you sure? I've AS 3.3 on OSX and if we are talking of the same functionality (filter dropdown - default: show only selected application), I still have it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LogCat is missing the filters options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714646/logcat-is-missing-the-filters-options)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It appears that this was just a weird UI state after the Android Studio Update. I changed it from "Docked Mode" to "Floating Mode" and the logcat filter bar returned and stayed even after returning to "Docked Mode".

Comment: FYI for others, *Floating Mode* and *Docked Mode* are under the "gear" settings icon at the upper-right of the Logcat pane.

Comment: Or just right click on the Top bar of the Logcat window to bring up the Floating/Dock settings

Comment: this did solve the issue for me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in `Android studio 3.4.2` version. I think it's a UI rendering issue.

By changing `logcat` tab's position to `top/left/right/bottom` filter options will be reappear. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It probably is a problem in `Android Studio 3.3.` I searched everywhere but couldn't find a way to make it available. So I downloaded `Android Studio 3.4 Beta` and `Logcat` is available.