# Android studio's logcat window loglevel filter missing

Tags: android, android-studio

[my printScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6z6e.png)

I don't konw how to fix it,even I have attempted to do these question's solutions,[similar question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311481/logcat-filter-missing-in-android-studio-3-3)

[similar question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714646/logcat-is-missing-the-filters-options)
my android studio version is 2021.3.1

Comment: this is a new logcat of the latest update (dolphin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is New Logcat (update - dolphin).

If you want to put filter of level then you just have to write `level:error`,`level:verbose`  etc after `package:mine` if you want a filter in your package.

Like here: `package:mine  level:error`

See below image for batter understanding

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

rightclick on logcat window's toppanel and try to swap View Mode. Mine were `Docked -> Floated->` then again switched to  `Docked`. The filter panel should appear as previously.