# Logcat not showing log level in android studio after update

Tags: android-studio, logcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdmej.png)
logcat used to show log levels such as warn, info, debug beside the filters but after updating it is just showing the search bar and not log levels

i tried looking up for solution but couldn't find any

Comment: what is the compileSdkVersion do you use?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 32

Comment: did you try to invalidate the cache and unplug the device and plug it again? Most of the time android studio creates this type of bugs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio's logcat window loglevel filter missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164792/android-studios-logcat-window-loglevel-filter-missing)