# Android Studio, how to see only my debug out

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting a lot of noise in Debug prints from the application interface.

I need to filter to see only my debug output. How can I do this in android studio.

For example, this is my debug window, how can I filter it to see only `I/System.out: 870.0  276.0   869.0   277.0` prints.

If possible, please show exactly where I need to do this int he Android Studio UI

```
I/System.out: 869.0 271.0   870.0   276.0
D/CameraBridge: mStretch value: 1.125
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) identical 3 lines
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/System.out: List for frame: 13
I/System.out: 870.0 276.0   869.0   277.0
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) Thread-2 identical 113 lines
I/System.out: 870.0 276.0   869.0   277.0
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/System.out: 870.0 276.0   869.0   277.0
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) Thread-2 identical 229 lines
I/System.out: 870.0 276.0   869.0   277.0
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
D/CameraBridge: mStretch value: 1.125
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) identical 2 lines
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/System.out: List for frame: 14
I/System.out: 869.0 277.0   133.0   329.0
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) Thread-2 identical 75 lines
I/System.out: 869.0 277.0   133.0   329.0
D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
I/System.out: 869.0 277.0   133.0   329.0
I/chatty: uid=10146(com.example.toolmap) Thread-2 identical 194 lines
I/System.out: 869.0 277.0   133.0   329.0
```

Comment: Use `package:mine` filter: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#special-queries. Screenshot here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164792/android-studios-logcat-window-loglevel-filter-missing/74165382#74165382

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio's logcat window loglevel filter missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164792/android-studios-logcat-window-loglevel-filter-missing)

Answer (score 0):

To filter the Debug prints in Android Studio, you can use the Logcat window.

1. Open the Logcat window by selecting View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat from the menu bar.
2. In the Logcat window, click on the search icon (magnifying glass) on the right-hand side.
3. In the search field that appears, type the filter you want to use. For example, in your case, you could type "I/System.out: 870.0 276.0 869.0 277.0".
4. Press Enter to apply the filter. You should now see only the Debug prints that match your filter.